# Filter rows by non-databse fields in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, filter

I have PostgreSQL and Django and theese models:

```
class TranslationService(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  service_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class GoogleTranslator(TranslationService):
 service_name = "Google"
 lang = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
 text = models.TextField(blank=False)
```

I wanna filter `TranslatorService` by `service_name`, but field isn't in database, how can I perform this? Only storing field in DB and set default field?

Comment: What could this even mean? `service_name` is *always* "Google", so how could you filter by it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, now I fix question

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. TranslationService is an abstract model, you can't query it. All the concrete subclasses are in their own tables, so doing `GoogleTranslator.objects.all()` will always only give you Google ones. So I still don't know what you're asking.